# How to write a simple function with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas. I have coded instructions I would like to repeat from one dataframe to another.

I would like to know if I can repeat the process by writing a function.

The goal is to :

1. replace all values of a column by a unique value
2. convert this column from one type to another
3. multiply the values of another column by the value of this column

Here is the existing code:

## 1. replace the values of the 'unit' column

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df.unit = '1000'
```

## 2. convert the 'unit' column values into int format

```
df['unit'] = df['unit'].astype('int')
```

## 3. multiply the values of another column ("value") by this value

```
df["value"] = df[["value"]].multiply(df["unit"], axis="index")
```

### **Is it possible to cast this into a function having the columns id ('unit', 'values') as variables?**

Thanks!

Comment: pandas is a python library, so the python tutorial is a good place to start: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function like this :

```
def your_transfromation(df,column1,column2):
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    df[column1] = ['1000' for i in range(len(df))]
    df[column1] = df[column1].astype('int')
    df[column2] = df[[column2]].multiply(df[column1], axis="index")
    return df
```

And call it:

```
df = your_transfromation(df,'unit',"value")
```